# Does Syntactic Category determines Position in the sentence and the Position in the sentence determines Category?

Tags: syntax, logic

<sub>Source: p 48, *Syntax, A Generative Introduction* (3 ed, 2012) by Andrew Carnie.

The following is NOT a homework question as I am not studying Linguistics but I have endeavoured to evidence my [effort](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/314/5306).</sub>

> In section 1 of this chapter, it was claimed that we needed parts of speech
>   to help us determine where in the sentence a word appeared. So for
>   example, we know that verbs and adjectives in English don’t function as
>   the subjects of sentences. Above we have given one test for part of speech
>   category in terms of the word’s distribution in the sentence. Here’s
>   something to think about. Have we created a circular argument: **[1.]** category
>   determines position in the sentence and **[2.]** the position in the sentence
>   determines category? Is this really circular? Does it matter?
>
> [p 47 states:] The part of speech of a word is determined by its place in the sentence [ie: Position]
>   and by its morphology, *not* by its meaning.

[2.] is true if only position, and NOT morphology, determines Syntactic Category.
So [2.] is false in general.

[1.] is false because Syntactic Distributions of different Syntactic Categories can overlap
 (q.v. third paragraph, p 50).

But because a false premise implies anything, 1 ⇒ 2 and 2 ⇒ 1 are valid (but NOT sound) arguments. Ergo the argument above is circular. QED.       Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

They're talking about section 1, not the complete set of all reality. This is called context. Presumably, the book goes on to explain why this rhetorical point is false.